# VS2003/05 constantly screws up the display - is there any known fix for this?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2005, windows-vista, visual-studio-2003

Running VS2003/05 under Vista makes the former screw up the display at least 50% of the time - you start debugging, VS kicks in and you see the windows/docking panes screwed up, not refreshing, etc... I've contacted Microsoft about this, but they weren't much help, I was wondering if someone knows any fixes?

I'm running VS with visual styles turned off under Vista, so that it doesn't hang when you try to do a "find in files".

All the latest updates/service packs are installed.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Sorry I am not any help.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2005 , install the 
[Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2005  Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=BB4A75AB-E2D4-4C96-B39D-37BAF6B5B1DC&displaylang=en)

and the
[Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Windows Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=90E2942D-3AD1-4873-A2EE-4ACC0AACE5B6&displaylang=en)

Take a look at the [Visual Studio .NET 2003 on Windows Vista Issue List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2005/bb188244.aspx) and see if you find something there.

And see if that help things.

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention - everything's up-to-date.

Comment: Even the latest video drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I've done a lot with Visual Studio 2005 Express on Vista, and have never seen any display issues.

Vista is pretty sensitive to the quality of the video drivers - have you tried updating yours?

Comment: Yep, everything is updated to the latest versions. And this doesn't happen on one machine, so I think it's a VS bug. I doubt they'll fix it though...